# If I remove a git submodule... is it REALLY gone from the repo?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have, for the last year, TouchJSON via a submodule. I no longer need to use the library and want to remove it but I am not sure if doing this: [How do I remove a submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-git-submodule)
will remove even the 'history' of TouchJSON.

basically, if I delete the submodule and then need to roll back for some odd reason, will it remember which version of TouchJSON to check out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will remember it; if you do a diff between two commits in which the only change is a submodule being updated to a new revision, git will report the two commit hashes of that subproject